# How do I extract weather description?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import requests

print('Input city')


city = input()

url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+city+'&units=metric&lang=en&appid=79d1ca96933b0328e1c7e3e7a26cb347'

weather_data = requests.get(url).json()

temperature = round(weather_data['main']['temp'])
temperature_feels = round(weather_data['main']['feels_like'])
weather_description = weather_data['weather']['description']

print("The temperature in", city, str(temperature), '°C')
print('Feels like', str(temperature_feels), '°C')
print(weather_description)
```

The code is supposed to output data about current temperature, what it feels like and weather description. But it won't output description.

Comment: What does it output instead?

Comment: '''weather_description = slice(weather_data['weather']['description'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str'''

Comment: `weather_data['weather']` is a list containing a dictionary with a `'description'` key. Get the dictionary out of the list first: `weather_description = weather_data['weather'][0]['description']`

Answer (score 0):

Exception

```
weather_description = weather_data['weather']['description']
```

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

you need weather of weather_data but it included in a list
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKzxj.png)

and if it not have description become program will throw an exception

I suggest you write like this:

```
import requests

print('Input city')


city = input()

url = f'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city}&units=metric&lang=en&appid=79d1ca96933b0328e1c7e3e7a26cb347'

weather_data = requests.get(url).json()

temperature = round(weather_data['main']['temp'])
temperature_feels = round(weather_data['main']['feels_like'])
weather_description = weather_data['weather'][0].get('description', None)

print(f"The temperature is {temperature}°C in {city}")
print(f'Feels like {temperature_feels}°C')
print(weather_description)
```

if description is not exits it will be None.
I do wish it can help you, and my english is poor, thank you.